wp show all the post of this categorie
In a custom taxonomy-category.php I want to show all the posts of this category, but with this code, it only shows posts if the category has more than one post.
What is incorrect?
<?php 
$loop =  mep_event_query(20, 'ASC', $term_id, '', '', '', 'upcoming'); 
if (have_posts() ): 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();{ 
    do_action('mep_event_list_shortcode', get_the_id(), 'four_column', 'grid'); 
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    endwhile;
else: ?>
<p class="avis-no-cursos">En estos momentos no hay disponible ningun curso.</p>
<p class="boto-negre">
    <a href="https://www.url" class="custom-link btn btn-sm border-width-0 btn-default btn-icon-right btn-ripple-out btn-border-animated cursor-init">Ver cursos disponibles<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
</p>
<?php endif;
?>


Instead of if (have_posts() ), should it be if ($loop->have_posts() )?

Also, get_the_id uses the global post, and I’m not familiar with mep_event_query, so I don’t know if it affects it or not.

$loop->have_posts(): We check for posts in a custom $loop request instead of using the global have_posts() function that works with the main WordPress loop.
$loop = mep_event_query(20, 'ASC', $term_id, '', '', '', 'upcoming');

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
        do_action('mep_event_list_shortcode', get_the_ID(), 'four_column', 'grid'); 
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

else : 
    ?>
    <p class="avis-no-cursos">En estos momentos no hay disponible ningun curso.</p>
    <p class="boto-negre">
        <a href="https://www.url" class="custom-link btn btn-sm border-width-0 btn-default btn-icon-right btn-ripple-out btn-border-animated cursor-init">
            Ver cursos disponibles<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </a>
    </p>
<?php 
endif;
?>

